# WordPress/WooCommerce/pmpro - Add membership to cart, if not a member

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Using WordPress with WooCommerce and Paid Memberships Pro.**

I want to force a membership onto the cart, if the user attempts to buy any product, and it should be non removal from cart. So If I'm not a member, It will add a membership to cart/checkout alongside the product I'm buying, and if I'm a member it will just redirect and let me buy. I have made the function like this:

```
function force_membership_on_cart() {
    if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('1')) {
        // go to checkout

    } else {
//force to cart here
    }
}
```

Since It's not a product, I can't use the add to cart function from wc. So what else can be done here?

Any suggestions here?

Comment: If is not a product, how you add it to cart then… We need to have an ID or something to add it to the cart programatically? Your question is a little un-detailed, as very few answerers get this commercial plugin… So you should add more details… Thanks

Comment: On a side note you can post the same question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com for better audience and visibility.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - The documentation is very light on the plugin, atleast for non paying users. In this example though, 1 (in has membership) is the id of the membership it has to check for, so it must be the same membership it somehow should add to the cart. PMPro has it own gateway, but very limited. Docs available here, if you are interested in that. I'm still looking through the files for a function.

Comment: @Jeet - wordpress.stackexchange.com is for wordpress help and not its plugins.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard you need to test your cart object outputting the raw data, to see how this plugin is working and how the data is arranged in the cart items…this is the first way to explore… I cant help more than this, as I have never see this commercial plugin in action. here you have a list of hooks related to this plugin: https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hooks-filters/